# How can I test a controller with more than one guard on NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm testing my controller but I'm having a problem to mock the guards of that controller. My app was developed with NestJs version 6.13.1

I can override one guard to mock it, as the snipped below:

```
const fakeGuard: CanActivate = { canActivate: () => true };

beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
            CoreModule,
            AuthModule,
            PermissionsModule,
            UsersModule
        ],
        controllers: [UsersController],
    })
    .overrideGuard(AuthGuard('jwt')).useValue(fakeGuard) // When I have one guard in my controller it works right
    .compile();

    controller = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    app.init();
});
```

But in my scenario, I have 2 guards defined in my controller

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), PermissionGuard)
export class UsersController {
    ...
}
```

I didn't find a way to mock more than one guard. I tried pass 2 guards when I call overrideGuard, but when I ran the test didn't work with any exception. But I know, the problem is because I couldn't mock those two guards. If you faced the same problem, share with me your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify each guard you are wanting to override with its own `overrideGuard`. You can have a `beforeEach` that looks like this:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  })
    .overrideGuard(Guard1)
    .useValue({ canActivate: () => true })
    .overrideGuard(Guard2)
    .useValue({ canActivate: () => true })
    .compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
});
```

Now both guards will return true and the test route could be hit successfully

Comment: Jay McDoniel thanks for your answer. I notice the real issue is to mock my custom guard. My custom guard receives 2 parameters, being a reflector and a service. Maybe these parameters cause the problem I'm not sure.

Comment: And look what nestjs reports: [Nest] 11812   - 2020-01-10 17:12:30   [ExceptionHandler] Object:
{}